# How to add type support for global components in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

So I have `Component1`,

```
<!-- Component1 -->
<script lang="ts" setup>
defineProps<{ msg: string }>()
</script>

<template>
  <p>{{ msg }}</p>
</template>
```

Then I register it globally,

```
// main.ts
import { createApp } from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"
import Component1 from "./Component1.vue"

const app = createApp(App)
app.component("Component1", Component1)
app.mount("#app")
```

Afterwards I use it as,

```
<script setup lang="ts"></script>

<template>
  <Component1 />
</template>
```

However I don't get type inference for props for `Component1`. So how do I add typescript support for this global component?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `vue` package exports a `GlobalComponents` interface that can be [augmented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) with your global component's definition. For example, you could add the module augmentation in `src/global-components.d.ts`, as [seen in the Volar docs](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/blame/1b90234ec6f10a3c0f080d0310711c2cd8de02dd/extensions/vscode-vue-language-features/README.md#L95-L100):

```js
// src/global-components.d.ts
import Component1 from '@/components/Component1.vue'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  export interface GlobalComponents {
    Component1: typeof Component1,
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how this can work already knowing that the PR is not merged yet. https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/3399

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on TSX components for some reason.

Answer (score 10):

I found @tony19's answer nearly correct — Volar recognized the component, but didn't provide proper type hinting. Instead found I needed to extend `vue`

```
// src/global-components.d.ts
import Component1 from '@/components/Component1.vue'

declare module 'vue' {
  export interface GlobalComponents {
    Component1: typeof Component1,
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between 'vue' and '@vue/runtime-core' ?

Comment: "vue" is a package that basically just re-exports most of the `@vue/runtime-dom` which itself depends on `@vue/runtime-core`. Im not sure why volar wanted `@vue/runtime-core`, but that is just what I found to be true. (see https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/vue/src/index.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I updated to match the module name you pointed out, and this indeed matches the current Volar docs. Interestingly, I don't see a difference when I use `vue` vs `@vue/runtime-core` (proper type hinting occurs in both cases). Can you give an example where only `@vue/runtime-core` works here?

Comment: Can you also the difference between `Component1: typeof Component1` and `Component1: InstanceType<typeof Component1>` ?
I understand that the second give the instance of the component, but which one is better ?

Comment: ** 2024 Update **

Both `declare module 'vue'` and `declare module '@vue/runtime-core'` work perfect now

Comment: thats true @BorisMaslennikov — updated to reflect that.