# Vue 3 library with global components and TypeScript support

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm building a Vue 3 component library using Vue 3, Vite, and TypeScript. The library installs as a plugin, and registers all components as globals. Here is how that looks:

```
// src/index.ts
const globalComponents = import.meta.glob("./components/**/*.vue", {
  eager: true,
});

export default {
  install(app: App, options: Record<string, string>) {
    Object.entries(globalComponents).forEach(
      ([item, definition]: [string, any]) => {
        const componentName = item
          ?.split("/")
          ?.pop()
          ?.replace(/\.\w+$/, "");

        app.component(componentName, definition.default);
      }
    );
  },
};

export { /* other exports */ };
```

I build the library using [Vite's Library Mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode), which looks like this:

```
// vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    lib: {
      formats: ["es"],
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      fileName: (format) => `bundle.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})],
    },
  },
});
```

Finally, my build command is as follows:

```bash
vite build && vue-tsc --emitDeclarationOnly && mv dist/src dist/types
```

This creates a `dist` directory, which includes a `.d.ts` file for each component. I'm able to import the library into other projects, and get TypeScript support for everything *except* the global components.

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645079/how-to-add-type-support-for-global-components-in-vue-3) that explains globals can be added using augmentation:

```
// src/global-components.d.ts
import Component1 from "@/components/Component1.vue";

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  export interface GlobalComponents {
    Component1: typeof Component1;
  }
}
```

I tried adding a similar file to the library, but that had no effect.

I added a similar file to the project and imported each Vue component `.d.ts` file from the library `dist/types/*` to provide TypeScript support in the project.  This works, but I'd much rather have this information come directly from the library.

So, that's my question.  How do I add TypeScript support for global components to my library, and make it available to projects that use it?

I hope that was clear.  Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: "// src/global-components.d.ts" - this code is supposed to be contained in entry point and should end up in package.json `types` file

Comment: I have tried adding those global components directly to ~/dist/types/index.d.ts, and that didn't help.  This is the file referenced by package.json `types`.

Can I add this file to src/, and somehow import it to make it available?  I'm missing something here.

Comment: I can't say what could happen when you add it to d.ts directly, try to add to src/index.ts, as this is the file that's responsible for this

Comment: I added the `declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {.....}` stuff to `~/src/index.ts`, and it shows up in `~/dist/types/index.d.ts`.  However, VSCode still doesn't recognise these global components when importing this into my project.  (I restarted VSCode, and no difference).  I can use the components, but VSCode sees them as type `any`.

Comment: Does it compile ok? VSC is a separate problem, it works independently from build process. You can try to move `import Component1` inside `declare module`, it makes it work differently and helps sometimes

Comment: Yes, compiles fine without errors, and I see the declaration in the `~/dist/types/index.d.ts` file.   I tried moving the import into the `declare module {...}` block, but that gives me an error: "Imports are not permitted in module augmentations. Consider moving them to the enclosing external module."